# POP3 Server Receiving Mail stops

Tags: email, openssl, pop3

I am writing a simple mail client prorgam written in C, but I have some problems when it comes tor receiving the mails from the server. After logging in successfully, I use the command "RETR n", where n is a simple number to retrieve one mail. I use a SSL connection and the problem is that not the complete message is being "downloaded", it just stops and the program stucks and does not finish correctly or does not finish at all. Then I also tested this with openssl in my terminal and get this error:

```
+OK mailbox "max.mustermann" has 4 messages (70911 octets) H miweb004
RETR 1
RENEGOTIATING
140235855091344:error:14094153:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:no renegotiation:s3_pkt.c:1261:
```

The code I am using to receive the email is:

```
//This should download all emails and delete them on the server
int GetAllMessages(BIO *bio) {

    unsigned char command_retr[] = {"RETR 1\n"};

    //Sends command RETR n to the server and retrieve all mails during a loop
    //Loop not added yet and 1 is constant yet, will be changed later
    if( WebSendLine(bio, command_retr, strlen(command_retr)) ) {
        printf("Error in GetAllMesssages: RETR couldn't be send.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ReceiveEmail(bio);      
}
```

and:

```
int ReceiveEmail(BIO *bio) {
    long int i;
    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    do {
        i = (long int) WebRead(bio, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }while( i > 0 && isend(buffer) ); //Do this until WebRead returns "error" or end of line was reached

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `WebRead()` does, but POSIX `read()` can return error for things like `EINTR`, `EAGAIN`, or `EWOULDBLOCK`, so the loop you really want looks something more like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[4096];
int nread;

do {
    do {
        nread = WebRead (bio, buffer, sizeof (buffer));
    } while (nread == -1 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK));
} while (nread > 0 && isend (buffer));
```

Next, I have no idea what `isend()` does, but I'm betting it's wrong because there's no way for it to figure out how much data is in the buffer without having access to `i`.

Thirdly, you'll never read 0 bytes from a socket until the connection is closed, which means that once you read all of the data in the RETR response, you'll hang until the TCP timeout occurs, so you'll need to actually check for "\r\n.\r\n" in the response (note: don't check for it in the `buffer`, because that byte sequence may be spread across multiple `WebRead` calls).

Comment: HI, at first I want to thank you for your help. :-) I will put my answers to your question in another answer text field below :-)

Answer (score 0):

The comment field was a bit short so this refers to jstedfast answer.
So WebRead just reads some bytes from the server and does some error checking on the included BIO_read() function included with the openssl headers

```
//This function should receive and returns a char to the buffer
unsigned char *WebRead(BIO *bio, unsigned char buffer[], int sizeofbuffer) {
int bytes_read; //Temporarily store how many bytes were read: for error checking

bytes_read = BIO_read(bio, buffer, sizeofbuffer);
if( bytes_read == 0 ) {
    //No more data available on an non-blocking connection
    return 0;
}
else if( bytes_read < 0 ) {
    //Error occured, retry and if this fails return  0
    if( ! BIO_should_retry(bio) )
        return 0;
}
return buffer;
}
```

And on [ibm.com site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html) it is just said that BIO_Read returns the number of bytes read, or 0 or -1. On a blocking connection, it returns 0 which means that the connection was closed, while -1 indicates that an error occurred.

The isend() function checks for "\r\n", ok it is not good written and youre right I should not just check buffer, but I guess it does not cause the problem and the isend() function has to be changed but I guess it does not cause this error.
Because it returns not the whole email it just stops some where, I guess if isend() would be causing this problem I would get the whole email and then stuck but the last bit of what I get looks like this:

```
 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Footer Ende -->
        <!-- /s1 -->
    </td>
    <td width=3D"15" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"https://img.ui-po=
```

I am looking forward to hear from you.

King regards
Greenality :-)